# Ionic Google log-in button not prompting pop-up to log-in

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, google-signin, capacitor

So I'm working on having a button where users can log into their account with their Google account.

The button works perfectly on `ionic serve`. Perfectly able to log into my account using my Google account. On my iPhone however, the button just doesn't do anything.

Haven't seen any other articles of people having a similar issue. Maybe I forgot to add app permission on iPhone?

HTML

```
<button class="google-div" (click)="auth.googleSignIn()">
    <img class="google" src="../../assets/images/googleLogInLight.png">
</button>
```

Auth Services .TS

```
googleSignIn() {
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
}
private async oAuthLogin(provider) {
  const credential = await this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(provider);
  return this.updateUserData(credential.user);
}

private updateUserData({ uid, email, displayName, photoURL }) {
  const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`users/${uid}`);
  const data = {
    uid,
    email,
    displayName,
    photoURL
  };

  email_out.setEmail(email);
  email_out.setid(uid)
  this.router.navigate(['/tabs']);
  return userRef.set(data, { merge: true });
}
```

Error in XCode

```
⚡️  To Native ->  App addListener 79051384
⚡️  [error] - ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: This operation 
is not supported in the environment this application is running on. 
"location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web 
storage must be enabled.
```

I'm also using FireStore as my authentication.

I'm also able to sign in with my Google Account with other apps on my iPhone.

Comment: Capacitor or cordova?

Comment: I am using Capacitor.